# Creating new projects with Eclipse 4.2 and SDK 20

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

OK, I'm trying to learn how to develop Android apps and have all the relevant tools installed. I also have access to several Androind App Development books that sadly were all written with older versions of Eclipse and the SDK.

So the 'New Android Project' interface is different but I can mostly get around those changes except for some confusion about new Blank Activities. I'm not sure, but I think that the old version of Eclipse/SDK would create a default activity called main.xml though most of the books I've been reading aren't explicit on this. In addition the default content of main.xml seems to be different.

Here's the new default code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I think the old default code looked like...

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    android:orientation=”vertical”
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”>

<TextView
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:text=”@string/hello”
    />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Not a big change I know but most of the tutorials in the half dozen books I've examined fail (with the exception of the default 'Hello World' tutorial which I've now succesfully done 6 or so times).

So could anyone give me some tips about what I should be doing when setting up new projects and what I should be calling the new blank activities or is my issue about the naming conventions of the Package Name.

Alterntively could someone tell me how I could downgrade Eclipse / SDK to something like versions Eclipse 3.7.2 and SDK around version 10 as most of the books seem to rely on those versions.

Answer (score 2):

Very difficult to obtain older versions of SDK as with every update, something is done for the better. Plus i would suggest you not to downgrade to older versions. Try to google, figure things out and get used to the new way! The only thing that has changed in the new SDK is how new projects are created. You could probably take a tutorial on it as rest things remain exaclty the same. So just for a few button clicks here and there, no point going to something old.

Comment: Thanks Royston appreciate that and to be honest I've spent the last month Googling, got to about page 100 in each of the books I've been delving in and still fail. The only useful tutorials I found that work were on the vogella website [Vogella link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) which were targeted at Eclipse 4.2

Comment: Yes, books take a bit of time to upgrade to the latest SDK's and Eclipses. You will appreciate that the new way of creating projects, though asks for more interactions, saves a lot of time editing stuff at different places later :)

Comment: I also found [this post](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-android-4-application-development/88531-right-versions-eclipse-adt-etc.html) useful.